# How to pass multiple arguments with url (routing) in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

LARAVEL 5.1

I want to edit my table which having ID and TktID.

I want to pass this two parameters to edit method of my TestController.

My link:

```
<a href="/sig/edit?id={{$value->id}}&ticketid={{$value->ticketid}}" title="Edit signature">
```

My route.php

```
Route::get('sig/edit{id}{ticketid}','TicketsController@edit');
```

edit method of controller:

```
 public function edit($id, $ticketid)
    {
        //
    }
```

How do I pass here two arguments in route.php to controller.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You forget end bracket

You have error in your routes.php file:

```
Route::get('sig/edit{id}{ticketid}', 'TicketsController@edit');
```

Should be:

```
Route::get('sig/edit/{id}/{ticketid}', 'TicketsController@edit');
```

Notice the forward slash after *edit* and *id*.

And in the view it should be either of the following:

```
<a href="{{ url('sig/edit/ ' . $value->id . '/' . $value->ticketid .')}}" title="Edit signature">
```

Or

```
<a href="/sig/edit/{$value->id}/{$value->ticketid}" title="Edit signature">
```

I hope this helps you out. Cheers.

Comment: ok how  about calling from broswer ip/sig/edit/ree will it work ?

Answer (score 10):

**Route**

`Route::get('sig/edit{id}{ticketid}','TicketsController@edit')->name(sig.edit);`

**link**

`<a href="{{route('sig.edit',[$value->id,$value->ticketid])}}" title="Edit signature">`

Answer (score 4):

```
 <a class="getValues" href="/sig/edit" title="Edit signature"/>Edit</a>
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value"={{$value->id}}"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="ticketid" name="ticketid" value="{{$value->ticketid}}"/>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var $id=jQuery('#id').val();
     var $ticketid=jQuery('#ticketid').val();

     jQuery('getValues').on('click',function(){
          $.ajax({
            url:'yourController/controller'sFunction',
                  data:{'id':$id,'ticketid':$ticketid},
         }).success(function(response){
                alert(rseponse);
            });
     })
});
```

**paste this line of code as first line in your controller's function ...**

```
$inputs = Input::all();
```

**and get values of input like**

```
echo    $ticketid=$inputs['ticketid'];
 echo "<br/>";
 echo     $id=$inputs['id'];
```

Comment: There is no form to submit.  Can this two hidden field will be submitted on clicking URL?

Comment: @martin now try this one it will work without having a form to submit

Comment: how can we pass multiple optional parameters and use them?

Answer (score 2):

As you are passing the parameters like this **?name=value**, you dont have to set up the route for it , you can directly access it in your controller by **Dependency injection**

you have to add this above your class

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Then in controller inject it & fetch the parameter values by name:

```
    public function edit(Request $request)
    {
        //
    $id= $request->id;
 $tkt= $request->tkt_id;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am passing two parameters like this:

**ROUTES**

```
Route::get('/add/{debitid}/{creditid}',
    ['as'=>'loan_add',
    'uses'=>'LoanController@loanset']);
```

**In LoanController**

```
public function loanset($debitid, $creditid)
{
    $debit_user= UserModel::findOrFail($debitid);
    $credit_user= UserModel::findOrFail($creditid);
    return view('load.add',compact('debit_user','credit_user'));
}
```

This example might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found this way to keep your URL the same way and access multiple parameters

```
<a href="/sig/edit?id={{$value->id}}&ticketid={{$value->ticketid}}" title="Edit signature">
```

Route

```
Route::get('sig/edit', 'TicketsController@edit');
```

Access the parameter values in the controller

Controller

```
public function edit(){
$id = Input::get('id');
$ticketId = Input::get('ticketid');
}
```

Note: import Input in controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Answer (score 1):

in `routes/web.php` file - This one works for me.

```
Route::any('/documents/folder/{args?}', function($args){
   $args = explode('/', $args);
   return $args;
})->where('args', '(.*)');
```

It should handle every argument/parameter now.

Hope it works !

Comment: how can we pass multiple optional parameters and use them?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to organize your parameters and their values in an array.

With your route defined like this:

```
Route::get('sig/edit{id}{ticketid}','TicketsController@edit')->name('ticket.edit');
```

```
//call your route like this

$params = [
    'id' => $value->id,
    'ticketid' => $value->ticketid,
];

route('ticket.edit', $params);
```

In laravel 10, even without the parameter defined in the route signature, It will still be passed to the route.